# Angular 7, component selector + html selector

Tags: angular, angular7

I'm trying to learn Angular 7 and i'm coding a Todo-List, for which i made a table row component and a general table component. The Problem is my DOM Structure looks like this:

*table > tbody > app-too > tr > td*

which destroys the table display

I already read a lot of blogposts answers (unfortunately for older versions of Angular), but none of these has solved my problem.

todo.component.html

```
<tr>
  <td>{{ todo.id }}</td>
  <td>{{ todo.createdAt }}</td>
  <td>{{ todo.description }}</td>
  <td
    (click)="toggleTodo()">
  </td>
</tr>
```

todo.component.ts

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo',
  templateUrl: './todo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todo.component.scss']
})
export class TodoComponent {

  @Input('todo') todo: any;

}
```

todo-table.component.html

```
<table>
  <tbody>
  <app-todo *ngFor="let todo of todos"
    [todo]="todo"
  </app-todo>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I've already tried the version of todo-table.component.html like so

```
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let todo of todos"
    app-todo
    [todo]="todo"
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

with my row component excluding the tr tag. But that gives a compile time issue:

*Can't bind to 'todo' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'*

I'm looking for a workaround where my app-todo element could be somehow like a tr element so that my table displays correctly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use an attribute (`<tr app-todo>`) instead of an element (`<app-todo>`), then your selector must match an attribute: `[app-todo]` instead of an element `app-todo`

Comment: Thanks! This works as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your input to `todo-table.component` which should be used in html .

Try using this instead of `todos` since todos is not defined in todo-table.component.

Also update your selector to use `[app-todo]` in place of `app-todo` since you are using `<tr *ngFor="let todoItem of todo" app-todo` as suggested in comments by @JB Nizet

```
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let todoItem of todo"
    app-todo
    [todo]="todoItem"
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Changing todos to todo wasn't necessary, since I get the todos from my service.